# How to group by one member and select a second member?

Tags: c#, linq

When I max over years how can I select the month for which the max value belongs to?

Please consider the following code:

```
public class Data_Point
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data_Point> Data = new List<Data_Point>();
    Data.Add(new Data_Point() { Month = 0, Year = 0, Value = 99 });
    Data.Add(new Data_Point() { Month = 1, Year = 0, Value = 69 });

    // Max should relate to one record only.
    var Max_Year = (from e in Data
                    group e by e.Year into y
                    select new { Month( e => e.Month ), Year = y.Key, Value = y.Max(e => e.Value) }).ToList();
}
```

I know my problem is not quite possible in SQL but I was wondering if LINQ is more flexible here.

Comment: why not `Data.Max(x=>x.Year).Month` !

Comment: Your code is confusing, try explaining what you are trying to do. Do you want the record with the highest year, including the month?

Comment: What do you expect / want to see (using the numbers given in the example code)? select new { Month = y.Max (x => x.Month), Year = ...;?

Comment: @Guvante I like to know the month for the max value per year. Does that make sense?

Comment: @chhenning a. Please write that in the question. b. You can simply that to max month per year, since two dates with the same month will return the same value for month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. However, if there are two different `Data_Point`s having the same `Value` equal to the maximum of the year both of them returned.

```
var Max_Year =
           from d in Data
           group d by d.Year into grouped_by_year
           let maxOfYear = grouped_by_year.Max(p => p.Value)
           from grp in grouped_by_year
           where grp.Value == maxOfYear
           select grp;
```

To have only one `Data_Point` (for example the first catch):

```
var Max_Year =
            from d in Data
            group d by d.Year into grouped_by_year
            select grouped_by_year.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Value).First();
```

You can change the last line to have the `Month` and `Year` and the `Max(Value)` only:

```
   select new { grp.Year, grp.Month, MaxValueOfTheYear = grp.Month,grp.Value };
```

Comment: When I run this code q would have two entries which is incorrect. Do you get the same?

Comment: Yes same result. But frankly your question is not clear. You want max and also you want month right? If it is what you are looking for then because there are two different months you get result with count 2

Comment: There can be only one max per year and this max value will belong to one months only. Hence for my test data the result should have only one entry. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Max_Year = (from e in Data
                group e by e.Year into y
                select new { Month = y.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value).First().Month, Year = y.Key, Value = y.Max(e => e.Value) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in SQL you can group by one column and select other columns by using min, max, average.

In LINQ you can do:

```
var maxMonthPerYear = Data
    .GroupBy(d => d.Year)
    .Select(grp => new { Y = grp.Key, M = grp.Max(grp => grp.Month) });
```